# How to change textbox text size and position of text in winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, fonts, textbox, position

I have a normal `textbox` which `multiline` property is set to true and now I need the text written in the textbox should have a `large font size`.So is it possible with the normal textbox.

As you can see below the look of my textbox

[image]

1.I need to `align` the text from `middle`(ie.. not from the `center` of the textbox it's `left middle` rather than starting from `top`.

2.I need to `increase` the `font size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the properties window in Visual Studio.

Click the textbox than find the `Font` property in the window. Clicking the `...` will open a dialog for you to change the font.

You can change the alignment using the `TextAlign` property.

Comment: Ah silly!I'm really stupid for a simple mistake I have done.Anyways thanks Ash Burlaczenko